# Is Kalshi haram?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, money, finance, gambling

Kalshi is a regulated exchange where you can trade on the outcome of real world events. They provide a place to trade event contracts. I'm not entirely sure if this is haram or not because it's not really betting like sports betting. But it's also not like the stock market—more so in between.

If I could describe it myself, it's like having ownership in an event or outcome of something. It's not like gambling because in gambling once you place a wager, it cannot be canceled or exchanged. These event contracts have their own value similar to a stock, and can be traded. And it has a probability factor similar to stocks. But it's not entirely like a stock, in that it is a contract, event contract. Any advice will help. Thanks!

Here is a link to their site [Kalshi.com](https://kalshi.com/)

Comment: At least to me, it looks like plain betting, and therefore it should be considered as gambling. That you can exchange your tickets for the bet on a special trading place does not change anything.